# How to test if a new file is sent with Active Storage in the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

In my Rails model, I have this code to force the filename to be changed when uploading:

```
before_save :set_filename  
  def set_filename
    if file.attached?
      self.file.blob.update(filename: "#{new_file_name()}.#{self.file.blob.content_type.split('/')[1]}")
    end
  end
```

The problem is the filename is changed even if a new file is not sent in the form (when editing).

My attachement is simply named file:

```
# active storage
  has_one_attached :file
```

How to really test that a new file is attached when uploading ?

Thanks,

**EDIT: more clarifications**

I have a form with a file_field.
I want to test if a new file is sent via the form, when I add or modify the object of the form.

My model is called Image and the attached file is called file.

```
class Image
  has_one_attached :file
end
```

I want to change the filename every time a new file is sent via the form, and not of course is the file_field stays empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [new_record?](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-new_record-3F) to check if `file` is new ie:

```
  def set_filename
    if file.attached? && file.new_record?
      self.file.blob.update(filename: "#{new_file_name()}.#{self.file.blob.content_type.split('/')[1]}")
    end
  end
```

Alternatively, use `before_create` instead of `before_save` so that `set_name` only runs when uploading new file.

**Updated**

Interestingly, ActiveStorage handles blob change outside model hooks. Apparently, it doesn't even support validation right now. There's no way to verify blob has changed as its state is not persisted anywhere. If you peek into rails log, notice rails purge old blob as soon as a new one is added.

Few options I can think of:

1.Update filename in controller eg:

```
original_name = params[:file].original_name
params[:file].original_name = # your logic goes here
```

2.Store blob file name in parent model and compare in `before_save`.

```
  def set_filename
    if file.attached? && file.blob.filename != self.old_filename
      self.file.blob.update(filename: "#{new_file_name()}.#{self.file.blob.content_type.split('/')[1]}")
    end
  end
```

None of these solutions are ideal but hope they give you some ideas.

Comment: I'm sorry but `before_create` doesn't work. When a new file is sent in edit action, the original filename is kept. The other solution `file.new_record?` doesn't work too.

Comment: I probably misunderstood your question, can you clarify what your expectation is again?

Comment: I updated my answer, interesting deep dive into what activestorage can and can't do

Comment: I used the second solution even if it's not perfect. I stored the active_storage_blob_key in my main model (in after_commit()) then I compare to new blob key in before_save()). Well, waiting for Rails 6 to see if new features will come. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have just solved this problem (or something very similar) using the `blob` record associated with the attachment.

Since the `blob` is an `ActiveStorage::Blob`, which is derived from `ActiveRecord::Base`, you can use the "dirty" methods on it to see if it has been changed. e.g.

```
def set_filename
  if file.attached? && (file_blob.has_changes_to_save? || file_blob.saved_changes?)
    self.file.blob.update(filename: "#{new_file_name()}.#{self.file.blob.content_type.split('/')[1]}")
  end
end
```

Depending on where in the lifecycle `set_filename` is called from, there may only be a need to check one of `has_changes_to_save?` or `saved_changes?`. Since, in your example, you're calling this in `before_save`, you would only need `file_blob.has_changes_to_save?`